# Disable both animoji and memoji

Tags: iphone, ios, keyboard

I can't seem to disable *both* animoji *and* memoji in iOS 13.3.1.  What I've done so far:

1. **Settings** > **General** > **Keyboard** > **Memoji Stickers** > **OFF**
2. In **Messages**, tap: **...** > **Edit**; then:

   - **More Apps** > **Animoji** > **OFF**
   - **Favorites** > **–** (next to Memoji Stickers) > **Delete**

...and it doesn't delete.

In playing around with it, it seems I can delete *either* Anamoji *or* Memoji from **Favorites**, but not *both* at the same time.

How can you disable *both* Anamoji *and* Memoji?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this.  I use neither, but I just ignore them.

Comment: I did the same thing on my phone and it's completely hidden. I'm on iOS 13.4 β so maybe wait for the next update...

Comment: @Allan Because it just _bugs_ me being there taking up space on my screen for something I will _never_ use.